# story featuring a bush whose stems or thorns grow into the fourth dimension

Tags: story-identification

I read part of this story sometime before 1987.  I can remember part of a genus/species name, *Rosa... something* and that the bush somehow poked into the fourth dimension.  I think the story itself was an extra-dimensional adventure of some sort, but that's all I remember.

Comment: [Rosaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosaceae)?

Comment: Almost certainly.

Comment: I remember reading something like this in Analog. A primitive prison used these plants as a security system by forcing the prisoners to eat a seed, and then they could control them by using the rest of the plant that was elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Might it have been *Rosacea karlsbadensis rufo*? Then the story is probably the one about [thiotimoline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thiotimoline) by Isaac Asimov.

The thiotimoline molecule has a geometry which is so abnormally stressed, that one of the molecular bonds actually shifts in the fourth dimension.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  I am familiar with Asimov's thiotimoline stories and they aren't what I'm remembering.